# Renaming filenames using python

Tags: python, renaming

I need to simply add the word "_Manual" onto the end of all the files i have in a specific directory
Here is the script i am using at the moment - i have no experience with python so this script is a frankenstine of other scripts i had lying around!

It doesn't give any error messages but it also doesnt work..

```
folder = "C:\Documents and Settings\DuffA\Bureaublad\test"

import os, glob

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        filename_split = os.path.splitext(filename) # filename and extensionname (extension in [1])
        filename_zero = filename_split[0]
        os.rename(filename_zero, filename_zero + "_manual")
```

I am now using

```
folder = "C:\Documents and Settings\DuffA\Bureaublad\test"
import os # glob is unnecessary
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
        filename_split = os.path.splitext(fullpath) # filename and extensionname (extension in [1])
        filename_zero, fileext = filename_split
        print fullpath, filename_zero + "_manual" + fileext
        os.rename(fullpath, filename_zero + "_manual" + fileext)
```

but it still doesnt work.. 
it doesnt print anything and nothing gets changed in the folder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I. e. it does nothing? Let's see:

```
folder = "C:\Documents and Settings\DuffA\Bureaublad\test"

import os # glob is unnecessary

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
        filename_split = os.path.splitext(fullpath) # filename and extensionname (extension in [1])
        filename_zero, fileext = filename_split
        os.rename(fullpath, filename_zero + "_manual" + fileext)
```

might do the trick, as you have to work with the full path. but I don't understand why there was no exception when the files could not be found...

---

EDIT to put the change to a more prominent place:

You as well seem to have your path wrong.

Use

```
folder = r"C:\Documents and Settings\DuffA\Bureaublad\test"
```

to prevent that the `\t` is turned into a tab character.

Comment: Again, with this one i don't get an error but nothing has changed in the directory!

Comment: Strange... You could put a `print fullpath, filename_zero + "_manual" + fileext´ before the `os.rename()` in order to see what happens...

Comment: Ouch, I think I got it now: there is something wrong with your folder. Try `folder = r"C:\Documents and Settings\DuffA\Bureaublad\test"` - the `\t` inside the string is made into a tab, which you prevent with the `r` prefix.

Comment: @glglgl Why don't you write directly: ``filename_zero, fileext = os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, filename))`` ?

Answer (score 5):

`os.rename` requires a source and destination filename. The variable `filename` contains your current filename (e.g., "something.txt"), whereas your split separates that into `something` and `txt`. As the source file to rename, you then only specify `something`, which fails silently.

Instead, you want to rename the file given in `filename`, but as you walk into subfolders as well, you need to make sure to use the absolute path. For this you can use `os.path.join(root, filename)`.

So in the end you get something like this:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(root, filename), 
  os.path.join(root, filename_zero + "_manual" + filename_split[1]))
```

This would rename `dir1/something.txt` into `dir1/something_manual.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

```
folder = r"C:\Documents and Settings\DuffA\Bureaublad\test"

import os, glob

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        filename_split = os.path.splitext(filename) # filename and extensionname (extension in [1])
        filename_zero = filename_split[0]
        os.rename(os.path.join(root, filename), os.path.join(root, filename_zero + "_manual" + filename_split[1]))
```

In your code, you are trying to rename `filename_zero`, which is the filename without extension and therefore does not exist as a real path. You have to specify the full path to `os.rename` like above.

Comment: Yep, there was a closing parens missing. Corrected it.

Comment: oop - fixed that, there was a missing ")" .. but it still just silently fails?

Comment: Works for me. It shouldn't fail silently, it should throw an OSError exception. Are the files currently in use by another application, do you have sufficient rights?

Comment: It just says that is has been terminated with exit code 00000000 and nothing in the directory has been changed!

Answer (score 0):

```
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        os.rename(os.path.join(root,filename),
                  os.path.join(root,'%s_manual%s' % os.path.splitext(filename)))
```

you should add a control in your code, to verify that the filename to rename hasn't already '_manual' in its string name

Comment: it definately doesnt - i have made some test files with random names!

Comment: @Alice Duff I was on the point to write there is a twist in your code... And now I write there WAS a twist in your code, because I've just seen that _glglgl_ has found the twist: you must escape the name of your folder. You're certainly on Windows. So my code definitely works.